# Maven release version build taking snapshot dependencies from .m2

Tags: osgi, maven-3, bamboo, maven-bundle-plugin

I have project A & B at trunk(1.5.0-SNAPSHOT) and branch (1.4.0)

B is having dependency in A
So, pom.xml for A:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>project-B</artifactId>
  <version>[1.0,2.0)</version>
<\dependency
```

When release build is given for A and in my ./m2 both release and snapshot jar is present i.e (B-1.5.0-SNAPSHOT) &  (B-1.4.0).

(B-1.5.0-SNAPHOT) is take as a dependency even after disabling snapshot in repository level.

If (B-1.5.0-SNAPSHOT) is not there in ./m2 its is using or downloading from nexus (B-1.4.0) as dependency as expected

Note:**Not using Maven release plugin**

we are using Atlasssian Bamboo for maven builds so there are cases when these scenario happens. when snapshot (trunk) and release (branch) build goes one after another

So,In my case how can i restrict the snapshots as a dependency if higher version of snapshot is available in my local .m2

Comment: Why not use ${project.version} instead of range version ?

Comment: Thanks.But the dependent jars version may be vary it cant be the same the ${project.version} therefore we have given range of version